# When and why should I throw errors in a Jenkinsfiles catch block? (Scripted Pipeline)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, error-handling, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

My Scripted Pipeline looks something like this:

```
Node {
    try {


        // If tests fail, I want to report the JUNIT results and skip the rest of the pipeline
        stage('Run Tests') {
            try {
                sh './gradlew test'
            } catch (err) {
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                echo "Caught err: ${err}"
                throw err // Should I throw this error? Will it prevent anything? Do I need it? Is it good to have?
            }
        }

        stage('Build Jar') {
            try {
                sh './gradlew fatJar'
            } catch (err) {
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                echo "Caught err: ${err}"
                throw err // Same with this one
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            try {
                echo "// if success, deploy"
            } catch (err) {
                currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
                echo "Error deploying, Caught: ${err}"
                throw err // Do I need to rethrow this?
            }

        }

    } catch (err) {
        echo "${err}"
        throw err // Will this catch all errors? Will I be missing stacktraces?
    } finally {
        junit '**/TEST-*.xml'
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/TEST-*.xml, **/build/libs/*.jar', fingerprint: true
    } // end global try/catch
} // end node
```

I am wondering when I should throw errors within the stage's try/catch, and if that is wanted for certain things (deployment) or should be avoided for others (testing).

If I throw an error in the try/catch will the pipeline immediately be exited?

The documentation is super unclear and in some-cases contradictory.

Comment: The try-catch-final will catch all errors generated by stage but you won't know at which stage the error generated. If you want to know that you should you should throw a custom error such as  `error "Run Tests Failed, please read logs..."` And throwing exception will exit pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

You should throw an exception **if you want to stop the pipeline**, and if you want a custom error message you can use the `error` pipeline function.

See:

```
            stage('Gradle Clean and Test') {
            try {
                sh './gradlew clean'
                sh './gradlew test --tests "*validateFiles*"'
                sh 'exit 1' // purposefully throwing this for demonstration
            } catch (err) {
                currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE' // Set to Failure
                echo "Gradle Clean and Test failed: ${err.getMessage()}" // Print Error Log Message
                error "Failed during Gradle Clean and Test... Check Logs" // Throw new error to quit out of pipeline, and give a custom message for final catch block
            }
        } // end stage('Gradle Clean and Test')
```

`echo "Gradle Clean and Test failed: ${err.getMessage()}"` will put the error message in the logs, for later retrieval

And `error "Failed during Gradle Clean and Test... Check Logs"` will send an error to be caught by the node's global catch block and can be easily seen in a Slack message if you use `err.message` in final catch block.